# How to define an exit/pop animation when navigating up (backpressing) out of a nested navgraph?

Tags: android

I have a navgraph that contains a nested navgraph like so

```
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/outer_graph.xml"
    app:startDestination="@id/startFrag">

    <include app:graph="@navigation/nested_graph" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/startFrag"
        android:name="com.myapp.StartFrag">

        <action
            android:id="@+id/toNestedGraph"
            app:destination="@id/nested_graph.xml"/>
    </fragment>


    <!-- destinations omitted for brevity-->

</navigation>
```

I would like to define a custom animation to play when popping the nested navgraph off the navstack (with a back press, in this case, not a defined navigation action). I'm unsure of the best way to proceed here.

I can see a few options for defining an exit animation, none of which are really ideal. I could `<include>` the outer navgraph into the nested one, define an action with an animation and `popTo` the original one while overriding the `super` backpress functionality, which seems like a bit of a hacky workaround. I could also override the back press pending animation manually but this also seems to be a bit of a hacky workaround, and a bit odd that it would be needed when both components are defined within a navgraph. I am aware that many things in Android are counter intuitive, however, and that the navigation architecture library is missing features, so one of these might be the best (or only) way to accomplish this.

Is there a better way to do this that I'm missing? Thanks!